# Package titlesec 2.10.1 in XeLaTeX removes numbering on sections and subsections

Tags: sectioning, xetex, numbering, titlesec

I've been using `titlesec` in XeLaTeX for quite a long time and never had problems with it. But recently, I updated it via `tlmgr` (as I have TeXLive 2015) to 2.10.1 and now I'm facing this situation:

When I load the package, section and subsection numberings disappear. I tried to explicitly show the numbering (see MWE below) without luck. Of course, when I comment the package including line (and its associated commands), the numberings appear again.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection.}{1em}{}[]
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection.}{0.5em}{}[]
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection.}{0.25em}{}[.---]

\begin{document}

\section{A fancy section}

\subsection{A subsection}

\subsubsection{A sub-subsection}

\end{document}
```

Here is an image of the output I get:

[image: Output of MWE]

I've never had this issue since I installed TeXLive. How can I solve it?

EDIT: I forgot to say I have TeXLive in another computer without the update and the MWE works fine. Here is an image of the output:

[image: Output of MWE in another computer]

Comment: A temporary bug: see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/MBd3-o2Dzx8 (the fix is already in, so you should be able to update via `tlmgr` already -- if not, sit tight and you will shortly).

Comment: @jon I've just did that but got no updates. Will try again.

Comment: CTAN has [version 2.10.2](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec?lang=en), so if you really can't wait, grab the `.tds.zip` for now.

Comment: @jon Thanks for the heads up! I tried it again and it seems the server where the program fetches the update hasn't mirrored it. I'll try with another server. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jon said, v2.10.1 of `titlesec` has a bug that the author (Javier Bezos) has already solved. At the time of writing, not every server had the update to use `tlmgr`. For those having the same problem, use this command (TexLive):

```
tlmgr update --all -repository http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/
```

That server has the update.

Read this link for more information: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/MBd3-o2Dzx8